# How to prevent my table's cells to scroll beyond the frame of my table

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I have created a table that is smaller than the bounds of its superview. The table loads fine and is in the position it is supposed to be in. The problem is that when I scroll, the cells scroll up beyond the bounds of the table view. How can i prevent this.

I already tried `clipsToBounds` property.

Comment: If you have a navigation bar, then it may cover the top part of the table. Or you can just add a view that covers the top of the table.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

TableView.layer.masksToBounds = true